# automatically duplicate wordpress post with different title and same content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website where I post blog for different cities and the content of all post are same

so, is there any way I can create multiple posts for multiple cities? i just have to change the title and rest everything is the same

Comment: Ask this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any plugin for post/page duplicator, after duplicate post/page you just need to change the title and slug.

You can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-page/

Or you can use which you like most.